# Django ManyToManyField doesn't highlight selected items

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to add a ManyToManyField to my Django app and it almost works. My only problem is that when I've saved an object and view it again in the admin the ManyToMany-fields doesn't get selected.

I set blank=True since otherwise it wouldn't let me save without selecting at least one item and I want the many-to-many-fields to be optional.

The whole many-to-many admin field is greyed out, that might have something to do with it.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3184097/manytomany.png

Model:

```
class Disease(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    vaccines = models.ManyToManyField(Vaccine, blank=True)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Admin:

```
from dbaccess.models import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Vaccine)
admin.site.register(Disease)
admin.site.register(Country)
admin.site.register(Medicine)
```

EDIT:
I checked and the disease_vaccine and disease_countries does contain items, so they are saved just not shown when the Disease is opened again in the Admin.

Comment: Do you have snapshot for it? Not sure what you mean for 'greyed out'.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3184097/manytomany.png

Comment: I just checked the database and the disease_vaccines and disease_countries-tables does contain entries so it seems they are saved, just not shown when the items are opened again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
class DiseaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Disease, DiseaseAdmin)
```